# How does the push-down automaton have to look like?

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

Could you give me a hint how to find a push-down automaton for the language:

$$L=\{ a^n b^{2n} | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

How does the push-down automaton have to look like?

Comment: Start in state $A$ with an empty stack.  For each $a$ you read in state $A$, push two tokens on the stack.  When you encounter your first $b$, move to state $B$ and pop a token from the stack.  For each additional $b$ you read in state $B$, pop a token from the stack.  REJECT if you try to pop from an empty stack, if you encounter an $a$ while you're in state $B$, or if the stack isn't empty when you're done reading the string; otherwise ACCEPT.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reposting [mjqxxxx's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849924/how-does-the-push-down-automaton-have-to-look-like#comment1752741_849924) because it hits the nail on the round flat part.

> Start in state $A$ with an empty stack. For each `a` you read in state $A$, push two tokens on the stack. When you encounter your first `b`, move to state $B$ and pop a token from the stack. For each additional `b` you read in state $B$, pop a token from the stack. REJECT if you try to pop from an empty stack, if you encounter an `a` while you're in state $B$, or if the stack isn't empty when you're done reading the string; otherwise ACCEPT.